# How to Split the row by nth delimiter in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have below data which is stored in a csv file

```
1|Roy|NA|2|Marry|4.6|3|Richard|NA|4|Joy|NA|5|Joe|NA|6|Jos|9|
```

Now I want to read the file and store it in the spark dataframe, before storing it into dataframe I want to split at every 3rd `|` and store it as a row.

Output Expected :

```
1|Roy|NA|
2|Marry|4.6|
3|Richard|NA|
4|Joy|NA|
5|Joe|NA|
6|Jos|9|
```

Could you anyone help me out to get the output like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading your csv file

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", "|").csv(file)
```

This will give you this dataframe

```
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4  |_c5|_c6|_c7    |_c8|_c9|_c10|_c11|_c12|_c13|_c14|_c15|_c16|_c17|_c18|
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|Roy|NA |2  |Marry|4.6|3  |Richard|NA |4  |Joy |NA  |5   |Joe |NA  |6   |Jos |9   |null|
|Roy|NA |2  |Marry|4.6|3  |Richard|NA |4  |Joy |NA  |5   |Joe |NA  |6   |Jos |9   |null|
|Roy|NA |2  |Marry|4.6|3  |Richard|NA |4  |Joy |NA  |5   |Joe |NA  |6   |Jos |9   |null|
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Last column is created because of the last delimiter in your csv file so we get rid of it

```
val dataframe = df.drop(df.schema.last.name)
dataframe.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|_c3|_c4  |_c5|_c6|_c7    |_c8|_c9|_c10|_c11|_c12|_c13|_c14|_c15|_c16|_c17|
+---+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|1  |Roy|NA |2  |Marry|4.6|3  |Richard|NA |4  |Joy |NA  |5   |Joe |NA  |6   |Jos |9   |
|1  |Roy|NA |2  |Marry|4.6|3  |Richard|NA |4  |Joy |NA  |5   |Joe |NA  |6   |Jos |9   |
|1  |Roy|NA |2  |Marry|4.6|3  |Richard|NA |4  |Joy |NA  |5   |Joe |NA  |6   |Jos |9   |
+---+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------+---+---+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Then, you need to create an array that contains list of columns name you need to have in your final dataframe

```
val names : Array[String] = Array("colOne", "colTwo", "colThree")
```

Last, you need a function that reads by 3

```
def splitCSV(dataFrame: DataFrame, columnNames : Array[String], sparkSession: SparkSession) : DataFrame = {
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val columns = dataFrame.columns
    var finalDF : DataFrame = Seq.empty[(String,String,String)].toDF(columnNames:_*)
    for(order <- 0 until(columns.length) -3 by(3) ){
      finalDF = finalDF.union(dataFrame.select(col(columns(order)).as(columnNames(0)), col(columns(order+1)).as(columnNames(1)), col(columns(order+2)).as(columnNames(2))))
    }
    finalDF
  }
```

After we apply this function on dataframe

```
val finalDF = splitCSV(dataframe, names, sparkSession)
finalDF.show(false)

+------+-------+--------+
|colOne|colTwo |colThree|
+------+-------+--------+
|1     |Roy    |NA      |
|1     |Roy    |NA      |
|1     |Roy    |NA      |
|2     |Marry  |4.6     |
|2     |Marry  |4.6     |
|2     |Marry  |4.6     |
|3     |Richard|NA      |
|3     |Richard|NA      |
|3     |Richard|NA      |
|4     |Joy    |NA      |
|4     |Joy    |NA      |
|4     |Joy    |NA      |
|5     |Joe    |NA      |
|5     |Joe    |NA      |
|5     |Joe    |NA      |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for most of it. There's no straightforward regex for "split at nth matching occurence", so we work around it by using a match to pick out the pattern, then insert a custom splitter that we can then use.

```scala
ds
  .withColumn("value", 
    regexp_replace('value, "([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|([^\\|]*)\\|", "$1|$2|$3||")) // 1
  .withColumn("value", explode(split('value, "\\|\\|"))) // 2
  .where(length('value) > 0) // 3
```

Explanation

1. Replace every group of 3 |'s with the components, then terminate with `||`
2. Split on each `||` and use `explode` to move each to a separate row
3. Unfortunately, the `split` picks up the empty group at the end, so we filter it out

Output for your given input:

```
+------------+
|value       |
+------------+
|1|Roy|NA    |
|2|Marry|4.6 |
|3|Richard|NA|
|4|Joy|NA    |
|5|Joe|NA    |
|6|Jos|9     |
+------------+
```